# google sheets autonumber android string

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets for a coding database. I want to use autonumber of a string.

<.string name="color101">hh</string.>

Please disregard the periods, this way it shows the full code.

I only want color101 to change to 102, 103 etc
everything else to stay the same.

I tried autonumber and either it repeated 101 and 102 or parse error.
Also switched my number order 101color and it just repeated.

In addition I have also tried to concatenate it by breaking down into different cells. It worked but I want to autonumber and auto combine the cells. I do not want to type every cell name.

Any help would be great, if this is a duplicate then please let me know.

Updated to address comments, hope this is clearer now.

Comment: i have also tried to concatenate it by breaking down into different cells.  <string name=" vru 101 "> あお </string> <string name="vru101">あお</string>   It worked but I want to autonumber and auto combine the cells. I do not want to type every cell name.

Comment: [edit] your question to include relevant info.  Don't put in comments. Also include clearer examples of before and after as well your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove all text from your cell (string) by using regex.
Simply remove text from your string and save new number value. `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,”[a-zA-Z]”,””)`